# Pandas - Filter dataframe using list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, tuples, filtering

I need to create a function that filters a dataframe using a list of tuples - taking as arguments a dataframe and a tuple list, as follows:

```
tuplelist=[('A', 5, 10), ('B', 0, 4),('C', 10, 11)]
```

What is the proper way to do this?

I have tried the following:

```
def multcolfilter(data_frame, tuplelist):

    def apply_single_cond(df_0,cond):

        df_1=df_0[(df_0[cond[0]]>cond[1]) & (df_0[cond[0]]<cond[2])]
        return df_1

    for x in range(len(tuplelist)-1):    

  df=apply_single_cond(apply_single_cond(data_frame,tuplelist[x-1]),tuplelist[x])
    return df
```

Comment: a sample input/output dataframe will be good, with improved formatting

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example dataframe and tuplelist:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(1,10), 'B':range(1,10), 'C':range(1,10)})
tuplelist=[('A', 2, 10), ('B', 0, 4),('C', 3, 5)]
```

Instead of working with tuples, create a dictionary form them:

```
filters = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in tuplelist}
print(filters)
{'A': (5, 10), 'B': (0, 4), 'C': (10, 11)}
```

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) to bin the values of the dataframe's columns:

```
rows = np.asarray([~pd.cut(df[i], filters[i], retbins=False, include_lowest=True).isnull() 
                   for i in filters.keys()]).all(axis = 0)
```

Use `rows` as a boolean indexer of `df`:

```
df[rows]
   A  B  C
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much nixon, that worked perfectly.